# How to close rmiregistry running on particular port?

Tags: java, linux, rmi, rmiregistry

I am working on Java RMI. I am having little issue with running my rmiregistry on port 2028 as I already used that one to run my test program. I can run my program using other port but I would like to know, How we can close rmiregistry running on particular port ?

Comment: Are you starting rmiregistry programatically or manually as a separate process?

Comment: No. I am starting it Linux shell like following % rmiregistry 2028&

Comment: If you are starting it manually, can't you also stop it manually?

Comment: I could not find command to do so. That's why put this question up here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do this in programming, we do something like:

```
// create the registry
Registry rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
...
// connect to it
JMXConnectorServer connector =
    JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url,
        new HashMap<String, Object>(),
        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
// do stuff with it ...

// close the connection
if (connector != null) {
    connector.stop();
}
// deregister the registry
if (rmiRegistry != null) {
    UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(rmiRegistry, true);
}
```

Here's the [full code for our JMXServer class](http://pastebin.com/1QWCrgNh).  We have problems creating 2 of these and completely unregistering them so we make sure to run our unit tests on different ports.

I use this code in my [SimpleJmx](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) JMX client/service package.

Comment: I am starting rmiregistry from shell. Not using it via program.

Comment: I was having a similar problem in Eclipse, where the registry thread would just continue running forever with the code snippets above. Added System.exit(0) to the end, which kills all threads in the JVM, and all ends well ;-)

Comment: +1 I was stopping the connector but couldn't work out how to get rid of the registry's server socket. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 11):

After so much of hassle I suddenly realize that rmiregistry runs in background of shell. So all we have to do close it first bring it to foreground and then close it. And it  worked.

BTW to bring it to foreground just type:

```
% fg
```

and then to close it type:

<kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd>

That's it. Thanks a lot everyone who tried to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running rmiregistry from the shell try to close it with:

```
Process p = 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef | grep rmiregistry | awk '{ print $2 }' | kill -9");
```

I'm not so fresh with shell commands, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I guess from shell I will have to use ps -ef | grep rmiregistry. I have not tried it yet. But I will sure let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @ Tudor: Sorry man it did not worked out... But I did found the answer to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If the rmi registry is already using the port and you want to rebind a service without using another port. You can try the code below

```
Registry registry = null;
try {
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
} catch (ExportException ex) {
   registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
} catch (RemoteException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```