# Why does JMX connection to Amazon EC2 fail?

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, jmx, visualvm

I set up JMX on one of services running on Amazon EC2 instance but it doesn't work properly. I'm using VisualVM to connect and after short period of pending it fails with timeout. Looks like it fails because of missing response data or lags. I checked that JMX port is enabled in security group and also tried with different port with no JMX enabled and also with port not enabled in security group settings and both fails immediately, so it looks different. My EC2 instance and desktop both have Ubuntu 12.04 and JDK 7 installed.

It turns out ports don't make sense since connection is SSL secured. I have a private key and have no idea how to use it with JConsole or VisualVM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to Java instances running on EC2 using JMX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734646/how-to-connect-to-java-instances-running-on-ec2-using-jmx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me. Set the JMX options on your server:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<some port>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

Open up an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key -D <some port> username@public_dns_address
```

Start VisualVM:

```
jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.system_socks_proxy=localhost:<some port> -J-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

Add a remote connection to the server. Add a JMX connection using the port you've specified for JMX.

To be clear, in all three cases above,  should be the same port.

Comment: I haven't tried but as far as I understand it uses ssh as local proxy. I have 8 different EC2 instances and that means I'll need to run 8 different VisualVMs?

Comment: That's correct. What I've done in this situation is to open one VisualVM to get the details about the MBeans I want to look at and then write a script to get them locally from each machine.

Specifically, I install JRuby and use the JMX gem to query JMX on the local machine and print the results to the console, or send them to a remote system for collection. This creates a little bit of load on the systems where the script is running, so you'll need to consider that.

Comment: Just a heads-up - you are leaving your JMX server completely unprotected (SSL off, authentication off).

Answer (score 13):

JMX needs an RMI registry operating on an open port. By default the RMI registry port is chosen randomly at the startup time and it doesn't play well with firewalls.
Since JDK7u4 you can use

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<port>
```

to set the RMI port to be used. Then you can enable that port in the security group.

Note the `.rmi.` part of the above setting because this usually gets confused with the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` setting. You should *not*!

Comment: I turns out ports don't make sense since connection is SSL secured. I have a private key and have no idea how to use it with JConsole or VisualVM

Comment: This should be the the accepted best answer, as it does not require an SSH tunnel or opening the entire port range from 0-65535 (as I saw suggested elsewhere).