# TITAN server monitoring via JMX

Tags: jmx, titan

Is it possible to monitor TITAN cassandra server with rexster remotely via JMX using something like VisualVM?

I have titan installed on the cloud and want to monitor it from my dev box.  Is this possible.

I have read this 
https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Monitoring
but it seems that JMX MBeans are only available locally however I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor Rexster JMX remotely with VisualVM, but it takes a bit of configuration and changes to `rexster.sh` as you need to include these environment variables:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

You can read some more about how to do remote setup on the [VisualVM site](http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html).

You mentioned that you are trying to monitor an instance in the cloud.  You didn't mention the cloud provider, but I've had trouble doing this with EC2 in the past.  Perhaps this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130877/jmx-connection-to-amazon-ec2-fails) will help you out.  While I've had issues with VisualVM remoting to EC2, I have successfully connected to Rexster via VisualVM from another EC2 instance without trouble so if all else fails that could be your workaround.

Comment: It seems when i checked that I already had these arguments but the port was set to 7299.  its a pity that I could not find this in the documentation for rexster/titan