# How to report JMX from Spark Streaming on EC2 to VisualVM?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmx, apache-spark, visualvm, spark-streaming

I have been trying to get a Spark Streaming job, running on a EC2 instance to report to VisualVM using JMX.

As of now I have the following config file:

**spark/conf/metrics.properties:**

```
*.sink.jmx.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

And I start the spark streaming job like this:
(the  -D bits I have added afterwards in the hopes of getting remote access to the ec2's jmx)

**terminal**:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --class my.class.StarterApp --master local --deploy-mode client \
  project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54321 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work, can you connect at all?

Comment: Adding the public IP to VisualVM is as far as I get. I can't get any further connection. I also have every connection in and out open as a security group of EC2
(I'm not sure if the port I supply with the -D params is even doing something)

Comment: Just for others who'll end up here searching for the solution (look at the second answer, not the accepted one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130877/jmx-connection-to-amazon-ec2-fails?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with the `spark-submit` command line:

1. `local` - you must **not** run Spark Standalone with `local` master URL because there will be no threads to run your computations (jobs) and you've got two, i.e. one for a receiver and another for the driver. You should see the following WARN in the logs:

> WARN StreamingContext: spark.master should be set as local[n], n > 1
>   in local mode if you have receivers to get data, otherwise Spark jobs
>   will not get resources to process the received data.

2. `-D` options are not picked up by the JVM as they're given after the Spark Streaming application and effectively became its command-line arguments. Put them *before* `project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and start over (you have to fix the above issue first!)

Answer (score 1):

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"/path/example/src/main/python/pi.py 10000
```

Notes:the configurations format : --conf "params" . tested under spark 2.+