# JVM metrics for java application running on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, jvm, monitoring, jconsole, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a use case to monitor the JVM metrics like(heap size,garbage collection etc) when my JAVA application is running .My application is running on EC2.
can you help me how JCONSOLE be used in EC2,or any other open source or will cloud watch help in doing this when my appication is running

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS CloudWatch metrics to have monitoring of the instance. You can use Datadog services to have extra monitoring. You can use [this document](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/) as a reference for datadog JMX integration.

If not, you can install JMX Directly on your EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can I use datadog in EC2 amazon linux to monitor java application or should i connect it remotlY?

Comment: You can connect ec2 with datadog. refer `https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/awsec2/`

Comment: actually my requirement is not to watch EC2metrics but JVM matrics for my java application running on EC2 can you help?

Comment: I believe you can do integration between ec2 and datadog and datadog and JMX, which will cater your requirement.

Comment: If not you can directly install JMX in your instance. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734646/how-to-connect-to-java-instances-running-on-ec2-using-jmx`

Comment: Thanks can youplease helpme with datadog and jmx integration?

Comment: I think this is a good reference for JMX and datadog integration. `https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/` . If you have any questions, post them as new questions, I will try my best to answer as much as possible. Hope this helps

Comment: @Manoj4068 I believe this answer is helpful and can be accepted.