# Java RMI registry port change issue

Tags: java, rmi

You can create a registry at a given port as follows.

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
...
Registry reg;
...
reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
```

That's fine. But how do I change the port number of the `Registry` (`reg`) when needed, after initializing it for the first time?.

I've tried to recreate, `reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port)`, but that gives some exceptions..

Comment: Please show the exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If this port is already in use by rmi you can't close it:

> It is a known limitation of the current RMI implementation that it
> never closes server (passive/listening) TCP port bindings for the
> lifetime of a virtual machine.> Blockquote

source: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508962

Maybe this can help you:

- [How to close rmiregistry running on particular port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386001/how-to-close-rmiregistry-running-on-particular-port)
- [closing rmi registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087163/closing-rmi-registry)

But please post exception.

Comment: Oh please. Read your source again. It *was* a known limitation, *in 2001.* That bug was fixed nearly ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a Registry at a given port as follows

No you can't. That code just constructs a stub referencing a Registry at that port, which may not even be running. The way to do what you said is with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry().`

> How do I change the port number of the Registry

Unexport the object returned by `createRegistry()` and call `createRegistry()` with a different port number.

Why you would want to do such a strange thing is another matter. What's the purpose?

> I've tried to recreate

No you haven't, see above. All that does is create a stub pointing to another port. It doesn't create a Registry. If there isn't a Registry running on that port the stub will fail when used.